# What to do at the Denpasar (Bali) Airport during a long transit?

Tags: transit, airports, bali

On my long (37 hours) way from Europe to Australia, I have a 14 hours (6AM - 10PM local time) transit at Bali Denpasar airport. Are there areas to relax and get some sleep? What else is there to do inside and/or outside?

(I'm traveling alone and am a 60yo woman not afraid of long walks. I also happened to have live in Indonesia for 3 years, but that was a long time ago.)

Edit: I qualify for the [35 USD on arrival VISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Indonesia#Visa_on_Arrival) and, depending on how well I managed to sleep so far, I'll consider getting it.

Comment: Are you traveling on a passport that allows you to leave the airport? If I'm remembering correctly, there's beaches right up to the perimeter fence if you'd like to walk those, plus shopping/a mall right down the road.